# Can a same application ear file be deployed in multiple cluster in weblogic server?

Tags: java, deployment, server, containers, weblogic12c

I have WebLogic 12c. There are multiple clusters designed and 2 managed server for each cluster defined. Now I have an application **app.ear**. I need to deploy the same ear in 2 different cluster. Can I do that ? Will it cause any conflict ? I am asking this because the deployment is done through jenkins pipeline which fetches the ear file with the artifact id [ for example **my_app (0.0.1-2020.15.15.13.19.52)** ]from nexus repo and then deploys in weblogic. The jenkins guy has designed a job for deploying in separate clusters, however one cluster deployment is causing the ear in other cluster to get deleted which should happen at all. I understand this might a job design issue. But can anyone confirm this.

If anyone has some lead to weblogic document containing this info that would be very useful to me.

Comment: 100% jenkins job issue. There is no documentation covering separate clusters, because separate clusters do not communicate with each other.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Yup..i also guess the same. Thanks for commenting. I will try to test this.